# Disable inspector

Tags: mozilla, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to disable inspector on a simple A-Frame WebVR app with no success.

Tried to use  and also disabling key press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> using JavaScript. But, inspector is still loading.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

My scene is really simple:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets><img id="render" src="back.png"></a-assets>
    <a-sky src="#render"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable A-Frame inspector (for production)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500453/disable-a-frame-inspector-for-production)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a disable-inspector component that calls the `remove` function of the inspector, and then use this component on the scene.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('disable-inspector', {
  dependencies: ['inspector'],
  init: function () {
    this.el.components.inspector.remove();
  }
});
```

and in your html file:

```
<a-scene disable-inspector>
  ...
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for 0.5.0

```
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
sceneEl.components.inspector.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The inspector is not bundled with A-Frame but downloaded on demand when opened. Disabling won't make any difference in library size. I recommend keeping it to preserve the open spirit of the Web where we can learn from each other. Are you worried about the built-in browser dev tools inspecting your site? The inspector is the equivalent for A-Frame markup. if you still want to disable you can do:

```
<a-scene inspector="url: xxx">
```

Comment: Inspector still loads.

Comment: Here is the code:
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   <a-scene>
   <a-assets><img id="render" src="myScene.png"></a-assets>
   <a-sky src="#render"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  <script>
   var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
   sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', function () { sceneEl.removeAttribute('inspector'); });

  </script>

</html>`

Comment: @Marcos Are there any update on this? In my application I don't need inspector event in development mode. Could I just completely remove the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Updated: `<a-scene inspector="url: blahblah">`

Comment: No luck either :(

Comment: @ngokevin Are there any update on this? In my application I don't need inspector event in development mode. Could I just completely remove the dependency?