# Disable A-Frame inspector (for production)

Tags: aframe

Hello fellow AFrame developers,

I would like to disable the inspector (Ctrl+Alt+I), for my production environment so the user can't open it and see the whole backstage of my game. Moreover, I'm sure that the size of my app will be significantly lower without this.

I can see that the inspector is never disabled in all the examples I found online, so I'm wondering if this is even possible...

[This piece of documentation](http://%20https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/introduction/visual-inspector-and-dev-tools.html#opening-the-inspector) mentions this :

`"Not only can we open our local scenes inside the Inspector, we can open any A-Frame scene in the wild using the Inspector (as long as the author has not explicitly disabled it)."`

But I can't find *how* to do it. Anyone has any clues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inspector is not bundled with A-Frame but downloaded on demand when opened. Disabling won't make any difference in library size. I recommend keeping it to preserve the open spirit of the Web where we can learn from each other. Are you worried about the built-in browser dev tools inspecting your site? The inspector is the equivalent for A-Frame markup. if you still want to disable you can do:

`<a-scene inspector="url: xxx">`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarifications. Maybe you're right, I should let the inspector activated, because it's the same as the chrome inspector but for a 3D scene.

The thing is, I'm making this serious game for my company, which sells it to our clients. And I'm not sure they would understand.